# Can Clementine music player fetch CDDB/FreeDB data?

Tags: audio-cd, file-metadata, clementine

A lot of players can get CDDB info about Audio CDs, but I have never seen that in Clementine.

Given the prestige and other qualities of this player It's hard to believe that it lacks this feature.

Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on perusal of the issues on Clementine's [GitHub page](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine), it looks like Clementine *should* have CDDB support, per [Issue#1239](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/1239) (which is marked as a duplicate of [Issue#314](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/314)).

The closing comments of Issue #314 indicate that Clementine uses the [`libtunepimp`](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/History:libtunepimp) library for talking to the MusicBrainz service for this tagging capability.  Unfortunately, per the MusicBrainz page, `libtunepimp` uses their *deprecated* web service (see http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Web_Service for more details).  Which means that Clementine may not be getting all of the latest-and-greatest from MusicBrainz.

Now, Issue #314 is more about get automatic song tagging support *in general* into Clementine, not necessarily CDDB specifically.  And indeed, among the open Clementine issues, there are a couple which suggest that CDDB support is lacking/not working as expected (*e.g.* [Issue#3067](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/3067), [Issue#4120](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/4120)).

So I *think* that the answer to your question of whether Clementine lacks CDDB support is *most likely*: "Yes, it's CDDB support is lacking enough to be considered missing".  Sadly.